# YCbCr Sampler in Vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan, yuv

I've been trying to sample a YCbCr image in Vulkan but I keep getting incorrect results, and I was hoping someone might be able to spot my mistake.

I have a NV12 YCbCr image which I want to render onto two triangles forming a quad. If i understand correctly, the VkFormat that corresponds to NV12 is VK_FORMAT_G8_B8R8_2PLANE_420_UNORM. Below is the code that I would expect to work, but I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do as well:

1. Create a VkSampler with a VkSamplerYcbcrConversion (with the correct format) in pNext
2. Read NV12 data into staging buffer
3. Create VkImage with the correct format and specify that the planes are disjoint
4. Get memory requirements (and offset for plane 1) for each plane (0 and 1)
5. Allocate device local memory for the image data
6. Bind each plane to the correct location in memory
7. Copy staging buffer to image memory
8. Create VkImageView with the same format as the VkImage and the same VkSamplerYcbcrConversionInfo as the VkSampler in pNext.

Code:

```
VkSamplerYcbcrConversion ycbcr_sampler_conversion;
VkSamplerYcbcrConversionInfo ycbcr_info;
VkSampler ycbcr_sampler;
VkImage image;
VkDeviceMemory image_memory;
VkDeviceSize memory_offset_plane0, memory_offset_plane1;
VkImageView image_view;

enum YCbCrStorageFormat
{
    NV12
};

unsigned char* ReadYCbCrFile(const std::string& filename, YCbCrStorageFormat storage_format, VkFormat vulkan_format, uint32_t* buffer_size, uint32_t* buffer_offset_plane1, uint32_t* buffer_offset_plane2)
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (!file.is_open()) { ELOG("Failed to open YCbCr image"); }
    *buffer_size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0);

    unsigned char* data;
    switch (storage_format)
    {
        case NV12:
        {
            if (vulkan_format != VK_FORMAT_G8_B8R8_2PLANE_420_UNORM)
            {
                ILOG("A 1:1 relationship doesn't exist between NV12 and 420, exiting");
                exit(1);
            }
            *buffer_offset_plane1 = (*buffer_size / 3) * 2;
            *buffer_offset_plane2 = 0; //Not used
            data = new unsigned char[*buffer_size];
            file.read((char*)(data), *buffer_size);
            break;
        }
        default:
            ELOG("A YCbCr storage format is required");
            break;
    }

    file.close();
    return data;
}

VkFormatProperties format_properties;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties(physical_device, VK_FORMAT_G8_B8R8_2PLANE_420_UNORM, &format_properties);
bool cosited = false, midpoint = false;
if (format_properties.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_COSITED_CHROMA_SAMPLES_BIT)
{
    cosited = true;
}
else if (format_properties.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_MIDPOINT_CHROMA_SAMPLES_BIT)
{
    midpoint = true;
}
if (!cosited && !midpoint)
{
    ELOG("Nither VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_COSITED_CHROMA_SAMPLES_BIT nor VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_MIDPOINT_CHROMA_SAMPLES_BIT is supported for VK_FORMAT_G8_B8R8_2PLANE_420_UNORM");
}

VkSamplerYcbcrConversionCreateInfo conversion_info = {};
conversion_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_YCBCR_CONVERSION_CREATE_INFO;
conversion_info.pNext = NULL;
conversion_info.format = VK_FORMAT_G8_B8R8_2PLANE_420_UNORM;
conversion_info.ycbcrModel = VK_SAMPLER_YCBCR_MODEL_CONVERSION_YCBCR_709;
conversion_info.ycbcrRange = VK_SAMPLER_YCBCR_RANGE_ITU_FULL;
conversion_info.components.r = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
conversion_info.components.g = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
conversion_info.components.b = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
conversion_info.components.a = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
if (cosited)
{
    conversion_info.xChromaOffset = VK_CHROMA_LOCATION_COSITED_EVEN;
    conversion_info.yChromaOffset = VK_CHROMA_LOCATION_COSITED_EVEN;
}
else
{
    conversion_info.xChromaOffset = VK_CHROMA_LOCATION_MIDPOINT;
    conversion_info.yChromaOffset = VK_CHROMA_LOCATION_MIDPOINT;
}
conversion_info.chromaFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
conversion_info.forceExplicitReconstruction = VK_FALSE;
VkResult res = vkCreateSamplerYcbcrConversion(logical_device, &conversion_info, NULL, &ycbcr_sampler_conversion);
CHECK_VK_RESULT(res, "Failed to create YCbCr conversion sampler");
ILOG("Successfully created YCbCr conversion");

ycbcr_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_YCBCR_CONVERSION_INFO;
ycbcr_info.pNext = NULL;
ycbcr_info.conversion = ycbcr_sampler_conversion;

VkSamplerCreateInfo sampler_info = {};
sampler_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
sampler_info.pNext = &ycbcr_info;
sampler_info.flags = 0;
sampler_info.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
sampler_info.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
sampler_info.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
sampler_info.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
sampler_info.addressModeV = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
sampler_info.addressModeW = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
sampler_info.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
sampler_info.anisotropyEnable = VK_FALSE;
//sampler_info.maxAnisotropy IGNORED
sampler_info.compareEnable = VK_FALSE;
//sampler_info.compareOp =  IGNORED
sampler_info.minLod = 0.0f;
sampler_info.maxLod = 1.0f;
sampler_info.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_OPAQUE_BLACK;
sampler_info.unnormalizedCoordinates = VK_FALSE;
res = vkCreateSampler(logical_device, &sampler_info, NULL, &ycbcr_sampler);
CHECK_VK_RESULT(res, "Failed to create YUV sampler");
ILOG("Successfully created sampler with YCbCr in pNext");

std::string filename = "tree_nv12_1920x1080.yuv";
uint32_t width = 1920, height = 1080;
VkFormat format = VK_FORMAT_G8_B8R8_2PLANE_420_UNORM;
uint32_t buffer_size, buffer_offset_plane1, buffer_offset_plane2;
unsigned char* ycbcr_data = ReadYCbCrFile(filename, NV12, VK_FORMAT_G8_B8R8_2PLANE_420_UNORM, &buffer_size, &buffer_offset_plane1, &buffer_offset_plane2);

//Load image into staging buffer
VkDeviceMemory stage_buffer_memory;
VkBuffer stage_buffer = create_vk_buffer(buffer_size, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, stage_buffer_memory);
void* stage_memory_ptr;
vkMapMemory(logical_device, stage_buffer_memory, 0, buffer_size, 0, &stage_memory_ptr);
memcpy(stage_memory_ptr, ycbcr_data, buffer_size);
vkUnmapMemory(logical_device, stage_buffer_memory);
delete[] ycbcr_data;

//Create image
VkImageCreateInfo img_info = {};
img_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
img_info.flags = VK_IMAGE_CREATE_DISJOINT_BIT;
img_info.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
img_info.extent.width = width;
img_info.extent.height = height;
img_info.extent.depth = 1;
img_info.mipLevels = 1;
img_info.arrayLayers = 1;
img_info.format = format;
img_info.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR;//VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
img_info.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED;
img_info.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
img_info.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
img_info.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
VkResult result = vkCreateImage(logical_device, &img_info, NULL, &image);
CHECK_VK_RESULT(result, "vkCreateImage failed to create image handle");
ILOG("Image created!");

//Get memory requirements for each plane and combine
//Plane 0
VkImagePlaneMemoryRequirementsInfo image_plane_info = {};
image_plane_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_PLANE_MEMORY_REQUIREMENTS_INFO;
image_plane_info.pNext = NULL;
image_plane_info.planeAspect = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_0_BIT;
VkImageMemoryRequirementsInfo2 image_info2 = {};
image_info2.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_REQUIREMENTS_INFO_2;
image_info2.pNext = &image_plane_info;
image_info2.image = image;
VkImagePlaneMemoryRequirementsInfo memory_plane_requirements = {};
memory_plane_requirements.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_PLANE_MEMORY_REQUIREMENTS_INFO;
memory_plane_requirements.pNext = NULL;
memory_plane_requirements.planeAspect = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_0_BIT;
VkMemoryRequirements2 memory_requirements2 = {};
memory_requirements2.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_REQUIREMENTS_2;
memory_requirements2.pNext = &memory_plane_requirements;
vkGetImageMemoryRequirements2(logical_device, &image_info2, &memory_requirements2);
VkDeviceSize image_size = memory_requirements2.memoryRequirements.size;
uint32_t image_bits = memory_requirements2.memoryRequirements.memoryTypeBits;
//Set offsets
memory_offset_plane0 = 0;
memory_offset_plane1 = image_size;
//Plane 1
image_plane_info.planeAspect = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_1_BIT;
memory_plane_requirements.planeAspect = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_1_BIT;
vkGetImageMemoryRequirements2(logical_device, &image_info2, &memory_requirements2);
image_size += memory_requirements2.memoryRequirements.size;
image_bits = image_bits | memory_requirements2.memoryRequirements.memoryTypeBits;

//Allocate image memory
VkMemoryAllocateInfo allocate_info = {};
allocate_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
allocate_info.allocationSize = image_size;
allocate_info.memoryTypeIndex = get_device_memory_type(image_bits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);
result = vkAllocateMemory(logical_device, &allocate_info, NULL, &image_memory);
CHECK_VK_RESULT(result, "vkAllocateMemory failed to allocate image memory");

//Bind each image plane to memory
std::vector<VkBindImageMemoryInfo> bind_image_memory_infos(2);
//Plane 0
VkBindImagePlaneMemoryInfo bind_image_plane0_info = {};
bind_image_plane0_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BIND_IMAGE_PLANE_MEMORY_INFO;
bind_image_plane0_info.pNext = NULL;
bind_image_plane0_info.planeAspect = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_0_BIT;
VkBindImageMemoryInfo& bind_image_memory_plane0_info = bind_image_memory_infos[0];
bind_image_memory_plane0_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BIND_IMAGE_MEMORY_INFO;
bind_image_memory_plane0_info.pNext = &bind_image_plane0_info;
bind_image_memory_plane0_info.image = image;
bind_image_memory_plane0_info.memory = image_memory;
bind_image_memory_plane0_info.memoryOffset = memory_offset_plane0;
//Plane 1
VkBindImagePlaneMemoryInfo bind_image_plane1_info = {};
bind_image_plane1_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BIND_IMAGE_PLANE_MEMORY_INFO;
bind_image_plane1_info.pNext = NULL;
bind_image_plane1_info.planeAspect = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_1_BIT;
VkBindImageMemoryInfo& bind_image_memory_plane1_info = bind_image_memory_infos[1];
bind_image_memory_plane1_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BIND_IMAGE_MEMORY_INFO;
bind_image_memory_plane1_info.pNext = &bind_image_plane1_info;
bind_image_memory_plane1_info.image = image;
bind_image_memory_plane1_info.memory = image_memory;
bind_image_memory_plane1_info.memoryOffset = memory_offset_plane1;
vkBindImageMemory2(logical_device, bind_image_memory_infos.size(), bind_image_memory_infos.data());

context.transition_vk_image_layout(image, format, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL);

//Copy staging buffer to device local buffer
VkCommandBuffer tmp_cmd_buffer = begin_tmp_vk_cmd_buffer();
std::vector<VkBufferImageCopy> plane_regions(2);
plane_regions[0].bufferOffset = 0;
plane_regions[0].bufferRowLength = 0;
plane_regions[0].bufferImageHeight = 0;
plane_regions[0].imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_0_BIT;
plane_regions[0].imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
plane_regions[0].imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
plane_regions[0].imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
plane_regions[0].imageOffset = { 0, 0, 0 };
plane_regions[0].imageExtent = { width, height, 1 };
plane_regions[1].bufferOffset = buffer_offset_plane1;
plane_regions[1].bufferRowLength = 0;
plane_regions[1].bufferImageHeight = 0;
plane_regions[1].imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_PLANE_1_BIT;
plane_regions[1].imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
plane_regions[1].imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
plane_regions[1].imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
plane_regions[1].imageOffset = { 0, 0, 0 };
plane_regions[1].imageExtent = { width / 2, height / 2, 1 };
vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(tmp_cmd_buffer, stage_buffer, image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, plane_regions.size(), plane_regions.data());
end_tmp_vk_cmd_buffer(tmp_cmd_buffer); //Submit and waits

vkFreeMemory(logical_device, stage_buffer_memory, NULL);
vkDestroyBuffer(logical_device, stage_buffer, NULL);

transition_vk_image_layout(image, format, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL);

VkImageViewCreateInfo image_view_info = {};
image_view_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
image_view_info.pNext = &ycbcr_info;
image_view_info.flags = 0;
image_view_info.image = image;
image_view_info.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
image_view_info.format = format;
image_view_info.components.r = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
image_view_info.components.b = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
image_view_info.components.g = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
image_view_info.components.a = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
image_view_info.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
image_view_info.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
image_view_info.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
image_view_info.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
image_view_info.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
VkResult res = vkCreateImageView(logical_device, &image_view_info, NULL, &.image_view);
CHECK_VK_RESULT(res, "Failed to create image view");

ILOG("Successfully created image, allocated image memory and created image view");
```

I receive one validation error: `vkCmdCopyBufferToImage() parameter, VkImageAspect pRegions->imageSubresource.aspectMask, is an unrecognized enumerator`, but from inspecting the validation code, it seems that it's just a bit outdated and this shouldn't be an issue.

The rest of the code just sets up regular descriptor layouts/pools and allocated and updates accordingly (I've verified with a regular RGB texture).

The fragment shader is as follows:

```
vec2 uv = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x / 1024.0, 1.0 - (gl_FragCoord.y / 1024.0));
out_color = vec4(texture(ycbcr_image, uv).rgb, 1.0f);
```

When I run my program I only get a red components (the image is essentially a greyscale image). from a little testing, it seems that the VkSamplerYcbcrconversion setup as removing it from both the VkSamplerCreateInfo.pNext and VkImageViewCreateInfo.pNext doesn't change anything.

I've also looked here, [Khronos YCbCr tests](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/VK-GL-CTS/blob/cd3bb68f8501cb96a4f92136c430f9fd23c0ec56/external/vulkancts/modules/vulkan/ycbcr/vktYCbCrConversionTests.cpp), but I can't find any real mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: according to the spec, sec. 12.1, *Conversion must be fixed at pipeline creation time, through use of a combined image sampler with an immutable sampler in VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding.*

By adding the *ycbcr_sampler* to *pImmutableSamplers* when setting up the descriptor set layout binding it now works:

```
VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding image_binding = {};
image_binding.binding = 0;
image_binding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
image_binding.descriptorCount = 1;
image_binding.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
image_binding.pImmutableSamplers = &ycbcr_sampler;
```

Comment: For those who copy paste the code from the question: There is an error there. sampler address mode must be VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE and not REPEAT. I edited the question with the fix.